# Return last value in table column

Tags: excel, vba, find, listobject

New to VBA. Been searching for answer for two days without finding a question that really asks what I want an answer to.

I am working with a UserForm that populates a Table in one of my sheets.

My problem is within the Sub `UserForm_Initialize()`. One of the first things I'm trying to do is to find out whether or not my last row (and incidentally, first column) in my DataBodyRange of said table contains an ID-number.

If it does, then I take that value, add one, and populate a textbox inside my UserForm.

If, however, the table consists of the headers and one empty row I want to populate the TextBox with the number 1 (that through another sub will be added to this empty row), but my code stops working with an error.

With the following code I get the error

> Run-Time Error '91': Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim tbl As ListObject, rng As Range

Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("table1")
Set rng = tbl.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange

If IsEmpty(rng.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues,_
           SearchOrder:=xlByRows,_
           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Value) Then
    Me.textBox.Value = 1
Else
    Me.textBox.Value = rng.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues,_
           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Value + 1
End If

End Sub
```

I don't understand the explanations I find regarding the error code or how to fix it. I gather that the fault has something to do with the `rng.Cells.Find...` because that's when the error shows up when stepping through the code, but I can for the life of me not understand why.

Comment: It will be `nothing` not empty I believe.  :Look at `.end(xlUp).row` also

Comment: Adding to @Nathan_Sav comment, you are performing the same search twice: once for your `IF` condition and then to update your textbox. I would declare a `range` variable and set that to your search result. Then use that in your `IF` condition and assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Find()` returns a Range, and if nothing is found, then the Range is Nothing. Thus, it should be checked against Is Nothing.

In the code below, a new range variable, `result` is introduced. It is checked for being nothing:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tbl As ListObject, rng As Range

    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("table1")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange

    Dim result As Range
    Set result = rng.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not result Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print result.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "result is nothing"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! I just added the `Me.textBox = result + 1` and `Me.textBox = result` inside the `If` statement above in order to populate my textbox in the UserForm.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because of

```
rng.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Value
```

If the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) doesn't find anything it returns `Nothing` and then you try to get the `.Value` of `Nothing` which fails.

Always test the result of `Find` for `Nothing` before you use it:

```
Dim FoundAt As Range
Set FoundAt = rng.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

If Not FoundAt Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print FoundAt.Value 'now you can safely use .Value
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
```

Comment: Exactly what I suggested.. although **'savely'** might be a bit out of place (in your comment in line 5) :)

Comment: :) your answer will work and is exactly what I would have done. My comment was not on your answer but the comment on line 5.. I suspect you meant **"safely"** and not **"savely"** in your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you don't really need `Find` for that as you can get the last cell directly:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tbl As ListObject, rng As Range, lastCell As Range

    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("table1")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange
    With rng
        Set lastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With
    If IsEmpty(lastCell) Then
        Me.TextBox.Value = 1
    Else
        Me.TextBox.Value = lastCell.Value + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Would this method require less work for the CPU compared to using `Find`?

Comment: Probably though I think the difference would be negligible. The results won't necessarily be the same as this method will always get the last table row, whereas Find will get the last row with data in the first column.